# Sub query in select list error Column 'XX' is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a sub query in the select list , but even though I use a group by clause it returns error

> "Column 'OINV.DocEntry' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

need some guide on this to solve the issue .

```
   SELECT  T0.isIns
         , T0.DocNum
         , T0.CardCode
         , T0.CardName
         , T0.DocDate                                     AS [Posting Date]
         , SUM(T1.GTotal)                                 AS [Total Gross Price]
         , SUM(T1.LineVat)                                AS [Total Tax Amount]
         , ISNULL(( SELECT     SUM(ISNULL(INV1.LineTotal, 0))
                      FROM       OINV
                      INNER JOIN INV1
                              ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry
                      WHERE      ( OINV.isIns = 'Y' )
                             AND INV1.ItemCode = 'SRRE00000002'
                             AND T0.DocEntry   = OINV.DocEntry
                             AND T1.DocEntry   = INV1.DocEntry
                      GROUP      BY OINV.DocEntry
                                    , INV1.DocEntry ), 0) [MarketReturn]
FROM       OINV AS T0
INNER JOIN INV1 AS T1
        ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE      ( T0.isIns = 'Y' )
GROUP      BY T0.isIns
              , T0.DocNum
              , T0.CardCode
              , T0.CardName
              , T0.DocDate
```

Comment: The issue is with `T0.DocEntry` column in the sub query. you need to add it to the `GROUP BY` clause or use some other way to get expected result for the `MarketReturn` column.

Comment: @JatinPatel  seems to be you put me in the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Final answer mentioned by @JatinPatel

```
SELECT  T0.isIns
         , T0.DocNum
         , T0.CardCode
         , T0.CardName
         , T0.DocDate                                     AS [Posting Date]
         , SUM(T1.GTotal)                                 AS [Total Gross Price]
         , SUM(T1.LineVat)                                AS [Total Tax Amount]
         , ISNULL(( SELECT     SUM(ISNULL(INV1.LineTotal, 0))
                      FROM       OINV
                      INNER JOIN INV1
                              ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry
                      WHERE      ( OINV.isIns = 'Y' )
                             AND INV1.ItemCode = 'SRRE00000002'
                             AND T0.DocEntry   = OINV.DocEntry
                             AND T1.DocEntry   = INV1.DocEntry
                      GROUP      BY OINV.DocEntry
                                    , INV1.DocEntry ), 0) [MarketReturn]
FROM       OINV AS T0
INNER JOIN INV1 AS T1
        ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE      ( T0.isIns = 'Y' )
GROUP      BY T0.isIns
              , T0.DocNum
              , T0.CardCode
              , T0.CardName
              , T0.DocDate 
          ,T0.DocEntry
          ,T1.DocEntry
```